# curl and wget not downloading files from a specific server

Tags: curl, server, wget, ubuntu-20.04

I'm facing something I never faced before. I searched everywhere without success. Take this image URL:

```
https://cdn.kimpex.com/Web/600/100/100659.jpg
```

You can see it in your browser. From the production server where I need to run an import, this URL seems to be not reachable. I tried curl and wget but I don't get any response. I tried from another server and it gets downloaded.

I have no idea where to check. iptables and firewall seem to be fine. Server is a Linode/Ubuntu 20.04.4.

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks!

UPDATE: The server can download from other server. For example running  `wget https://www.example.com`:

```
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946, 93.184.216.34
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1256 (1.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html 100%[============================>]   1.23K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2022-06-10 17:33:11 (90.2 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [1256/1256]
```

Comment: Can you get `wget` to download anything from that server? Please try `wget https://www.example.com` and then write what happen

Comment: Yes @Daweo I can totally download:
`--2022-06-10 17:33:11--  https://www.example.com/
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946, 93.184.216.34
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1256 (1.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                                     100%[============>]   1.23K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2022-06-10 17:33:11 (90.2 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [1256/1256]`

Comment: To me, it seems clear that the server I'm trying to access is blocking my server. I mean I can't think of other reasons honestly...